# Magento Cart Checkout doesn't display TAX anymore?

Tags: magento, checkout

Since a few weeks I'm working with Magento. I've been doing all the work myself, but this time i've hit a problem which I can't solve.

I've got a problem with my shopping cart. I live in the Netherlands where it's usuall to add 19% TAX to all the products. So products, shipping costs and all that are ALWAYS displayed with TAX. In the store, all my products are displayed with TAX. However, in the shopping cart and the checkout proces they aren't. Now I've installed the Dutch Shop Settings for magento. This plugin worked with my normal checkout, but I've also installed Golden Spiral Studio One Click Cart Checkout 2.0 which workes fine, accept for the TAX.

Bottom line: Since my One Click Cart Checkout, al my products are displayed without tax again. Changing something in the configuration doensn't help! I need to go deeper.

Have a look in my store at www.phone-gadgets.com for the problem. Order a product and you will see.

Answer (score 3):

In your admin go to System > Configuration > Shipping Settings, and then fill out all the details under Origin. This can affect the tax being applied to your location.